# Asp.Net Grid - Make first character in uppercase of Grid Row

Tags: asp.net

Below code works fine, and bind datatable to asp.net Grid

```
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        Grid1.DataSource = ds;
        Grid1.DataBind();

                 <asp:GridView ID="Grid1" runat="server" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="4" OnRowDataBound="Grid1_OnRowDataBound">
                 </asp:GridView>
```

First row in Grid, displays text like this- "the quick brown fox jumps"

How to display this in grid - "The quick brown fox jumps"

First character needs to be capitalized.

Comment: What you use in your grid to show it? TemplateFields? Show your aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the [`RowDataBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound?view=netframework-4.7.2) event.

Presuming you use `BoundFields` and the text is in the first column:

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string oldText = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldText))
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = char.ToUpper(oldText[0]) + (oldText.Length > 1 ? oldText.Substring(1) : "");
    }
}
```